# How to get 2nd AVERAGEIFS formula to takeover if 1st AVERAGEIFS formula doesn't work (Google Sheets)? (Use IFERROR or SUMPRODUCT??)

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, average

I'm trying to get an `AVERAGEIF` a few conditions are met (from another sheet: **SHEET1**). If the conditions aren't met, then I want a different `AVERAGEIFS` formula to go into effect.

Not sure how to combine these two arguments. They work fine on their own, but I want **Formula 2** to work if **Formula 1**'s conditions aren't met.

Should I be using `SUMPRODUCT` or nest these formulas together? Would appreciate some help combining these.

---

**Formula 1**

`=AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3)`

- where range to average: R3:R105

  A3:A105 = x

  S3:S105 contains EWS

  D3:D105 = SAV

  ***Q3:Q105 date within past 3 years***    <-- reason Formula 1 fails is because this last condition is not met

.

### If cell doesn’t meet Formula 1's conditions, then activate Formula 2:

.

**Formula 2**

`=AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!B3:B105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3)`

- where range to average: R3:R105
  A3:A105 = x

  S3:S105 contains EWS

  D3:D105 = SAV

  B3:B105 date within past 3 years

---

I tried a few things, but they ended up with errors. Is there a way to use the `IFERROR` function? I tried to substitute **Formula 2** into `value_if_error`, but got another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try:

```
=iferror(your-ave-1,iferror(your-ave2,"check"))
```

If it returns “check” then both your average calcs have not worked. Quotes (") now corrected- a font on the smartphone...

I have not checked your average calcs as I am using a smartphone..

### EDIT

updated the formula to include the correct "

`=iferror(Formula 1,iferror(Formula 2,"check"))`

substituted formulas:

`=iferror(AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),iferror(AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!P3:P107, "<>"), "check"))`

Comment: thanks! i tried your formula, substituting my formulas in, but i got an error saying i'm missing a parenthesis. i tried adding one more at the end, but still the same error... here is the formula: `=iferror(AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),iferror(AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1!B3:B105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),”check”)))`

Comment: i modified the formula a bit. the issue was  the formula you gave had `""` going backwards(?) which apparently gsheets is finnicky about lol when i use the modified formula below, i get **check** instead of the avg of R3:R107. i understand `IFERROR` formula gives `check` instead of `ERROR` but why is it giving an error? there should be an avg. i can manually avg the values when i filter/sort, but i'd like it to be dynamic. formula: `=iferror(your-ave-1,iferror(your-ave2,"check"))

Comment: so i figured out that my **Formula 2** was slightly off. I changed parameters for last condition. It now gives me an average correctly!! my new formula `=iferror(AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),iferror(AVERAGEIFS('SHEET1'!R3:R105, 'SHEET1'!A3:A105, "x", 'SHEET1'!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 'SHEET1'!D3:D105, "SAV", 'SHEET1'!P3:P107, "<>"), "check"))`  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Excellent -glad it works for you. And the quotes thing is a font on the smartphone ...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(SHEET1!Q3:Q105 > month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3,
                         AVERAGEIFS(SHEET1!R3:R105, SHEET1!A3:A105, "x", SHEET1!S3:S105, "*EWS*", SHEET1!D3:D105, "SAV", SHEET1!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),
                         AVERAGEIFS(SHEET1!R3:R105, SHEET1!A3:A105, "x", SHEET1!S3:S105, "*EWS*", SHEET1!D3:D105, "SAV", SHEET1!B3:B105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3))),)
```

**update:**

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula (IF (SHEET1!Q3:Q105 > month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3,                       
AVERAGEIFS(SHEET1!R3:R105, SHEET1!A3:A105, "x", 
                           SHEET1!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 
                           SHEET1!D3:D105, "SAV", 
                           SHEET1!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),                      
AVERAGEIFS(SHEET1!R3:R105, SHEET1!A3:A105, "x", 
                           SHEET1!S3:S105, "*EWS*", 
                           SHEET1!D3:D105, "SAV", 
                           SHEET1!B3:B105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3))),)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. i tried it out and kept getting an error, saying i was missing a parentheses

Comment: i added some and then changed the formula to: `=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(SHEET1!Q3:Q105 > month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),                       AVERAGEIFS(SHEET1!R3:R105, SHEET1!A3:A105, "x", SHEET1!S3:S105, "*EWS*", SHEET1!D3:D105, SAV", SHEET1!Q3:Q105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3),                      AVERAGEIFS(SHEET1!R3:R105, SHEET1!A3:A105, "x", SHEET1!S3:S105, "*EWS*", SHEET1!D3:D105, "SAV", SHEET1!B3:B105, ">"&month(today())&"/"&day(today())&"/"&year(Today())-3)),)` unfortunately, it didnt work; gave a blank (even though should give #)

Comment: @quesyrahsarah yeah, your formula from comment was broken